# Azure Search SDK orderby case sensitve results issue

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I need some assistant with Azure Search (AS) SDK settings. I have an index with a column that IsSortable in the index and I am using the default orderby of ascending (asc). Results return no problem and work as expected until the data in that column has a mix of case such as Title, upper and lower.

This is an example of what AS is giving me:

1. Apple
2. PEAR
3. Peach
4. apple
5. peach
6. pear

This is what I would expect to see:

1. apple
2. Apple
3. peach
4. Peach
5. pear
6. PEAR

This is my current search parameter setting:

```
SearchParameters sp = new SearchParameters()
            {
                OrderBy = new string[] { "sortcolumn" },
                IncludeTotalResultCount = true,
                SearchMode = SearchMode.Any,
                Top = 60                  
            };
```

Is there any way to set azure to ignore case in ordering as I can't find any documentation.

Thanks
Rob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, there's no built-in way to do case-insensitive sorting. One way to do this is to add a field to your index with case-normalized values and sort by that field.

Please vote for [this UserVoice suggestion](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/6328658-case-insensitive-sorting-for-string-fields)to help us prioritize this work. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the response. Your suggestion was something I was trying to avoid but thanks for the link to UV. I have voted